# Upload repository on compiled

Tags: linux, git, unix, github

I'm just wondering if there is a way (Linux / Unix) to update a Github repository when a particular file has compiled successfully?

So for example, I have a repository called 'Work' and if I compiled the file `main.cpp` and if it compiles successfully it automatically synchronises the file / repository on Github.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me :)!

Thankss  :)

Comment: Git is not a backup solution.

Comment: @BatchyX I do not want Github as a back-up solution.. I just want to make sure that the code I write / Compile is up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just wondering if there is a way (Linux / Unix) to update a Github
>   repository when a particular file has compiled successfully?

If you can get and analyze results of running gcc (exit-code or grepping output), you can do **what you want** in rather easy and small (2-3-liner) shell script, can't see any troubles here.

From my side I see your workflow as not bullet-proof (if you push sporadically, you have good chances to lost a lot of local work in case of disaster), just for sake I'll prefer "push all, tag compilable changeset"

Answer (score 2):

You can do the other way. If you write proper [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) commit will success only if `main.cpp` will compile.

Comment: Hey, but it would have to be on the file that has just been compiled.. Even if it was set inside a variable (for example) e.g. file = "main.cpp" -> file = "somethingelse.cpp"